# TemplateDoesNotExist, but file found

Tags: python, django

I get a weird TemplateDoesNotExist-error in my Django-project. The loader actually finds a template file (which also exists and I want to call!). Here is the output:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    [...]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/osm/index.html (File does not exist)
    [...]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/osm/index.html (File does not exist)
    [...]/projekt/osm/templates/osm/index.html (File exists)
    [...]/projekt/flotte/templates/osm/index.html (File does not exist)
```

Why is the error thrown even though a file is found?

EDIT: after some testing it seems as all HTML-templates which extend my `base.html` don't work while stand-alone html-templates work:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block main_content %}
[...]
```

My `base.html` is located in `[...]/projekt/static/templates`. This path is defined in TEMPLATE_DIRS. Pretty sure this worked before updating to django 1.8.2! :(

How do I make the project-template-path `[...]/projekt/static/templates`

my settings: [full see http://pastebin.com/rn2hSj5Y]

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
#Template location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "templates"),
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "osm", "templates", "osm"),
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "flotte", "templates", "flotte"),
)
```

my corresponding view:

```
def index(request):
    # Request the context of the request.
    # The context contains information such as the client's machine details, for example.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"}

    return render_to_response('osm/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the file?

Comment: Yes, `[...]/projekt/osm/templates/osm/index.html` is readable:  `-rwxrwxr-- 1 user plugdev  982 Oct  5  2014 index.html*`

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using Django 1.8 - what version are you on? 1.8 changes the template settings.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.2, but the settings-file as well as the app 'OSM' were written for 1.7, I believe. Please check out my EDIT about which HTMLs fail!

Answer (score 0):

If osm , flotte are apps , just remove these two lines from TEMPLATE_DIRS :

```
 os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "osm", "templates", "osm"),
 os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "flotte", "templates", "flotte"),
```

as  they are already found by the app directories loader. TEMPLATE_DIRS is for non-app templates.

Comment: Hey amr, thanks for you answer. I tried this but I couldn't find that it made a difference. Do I have to do anything beside restarting the server after I changed settings.py to deploy the changes?